I want to hide column dynamically in BIP report
I want to dynamically hide the columns if the value is there. If value is there then I want to hide that column else It should display with some constant value.
Can we do it in BIP RTF template ?
Thanks

I guess you'll have to use IF.
For example, there's a CB_SHOW_IT which is 0 (don't show it) or 1 (show it). You'd then
<?if:CB_SHOW_IT>’0’?>

Display some value here.

<?end if?>

